# Blur Event Does not get Fired in IE7 and IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onblur

I have a dropdown Menu where in a div is clicked and List is shown.

On focus out I am supposed to hide the list(i.e. when the user clicks or focuses on some other element and not on mouse out). Hence my obvious choice was `onblur`.

Now the JavaScript seems to work in Firefox but not in IE thats because my div has a sub div with a height and width specified. This is reproducible in a test file. I am using jQuery.

Is this a known issues in Internet Explorer? And what is the work around?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exploring IE</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      /** Exploring IE**/
      .selected_option div {height:18px;}
    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min9919.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function(){
        $('.selected_option').blur(function(){
          alert('blurred');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="selected_option" tabindex="0">
      <div>anywhere in the page</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it with bind and still the same problem persists. Its working fine in all browsers except IE.

Comment: There is no Tabindex attribute for div element

Answer (score 7):

The IE-proprietary `focusout` event worked for me:

```
$('.selected_option').bind('focusout', function(){
    alert('focusout');
});
```

Again, this is proprietary (see [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)) but may be appropriate if it solves your problem. You could always bind to both the `blur` and `focusout` events.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This solved my problems with IE7. First tried live('focusout'), but that did not work, and then bind() which worked for ie7.

Answer (score 2):

```
onkeypress="this.blur(); return false;"
```

its works fine on all IE versions

Answer (score 1):

First realize that `focus` and `blur` events are only supported on [focusable elements](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html). To make your `<div>`s focusable you need to look at the [`tabindex` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550049/focus-on-a-non-input-anchor-element).

Answer (score 1):

Try using an anchor tag instead of a div since these are naively focusable. You can set the href of the anchor to "javascript:void(0)" to prevent it from actually linking to a pageand use the css property "display: block" to make it render like a div. Something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exploring IE</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      /** Exploring IE**/
      .selected_option
      {
        display: block;
        height:18px;
      }
    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min9919.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function(){
        $('.selected_option').blur(function(){
          alert('blurred');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="selected_option">anywhere in the page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.selected_option').bind('blur', function(){           
          alert('blurred');
});
```

Also you can make another trick - handle all mouse clicks or/and focus events and if some another control is selected, then your own is blurred (of course if it was selected previously).

Answer (score 0):

I have set the tabIndex property for the div to be focusable and moreover if i comment the height the blur event is fired so I assume thats not the problem.

Comment: either edit your question or comment on someone's answer. do not post your own answer unless you figured it out and it answers your original question.