# jQuery blur handler not working on div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I don't understand why the jQuery blur handler isn't working in the most simple case. I'm literally creating a div 100px by 100px and setting a blur event on it, but it's not firing ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhLn8/)):

```
<div id="test">this is a test</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').bind('blur', function() {
          alert('blur event!'); 
    });
});
```

Is my understanding of blur wrong? I expect the blur event to fire when I click anywhere that is not the div...right?

According to jQuery's documentation:

> In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to
>   include ***all element types***. An element can lose focus via keyboard
>   commands, such as the Tab key, ***or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the
>   page.***

I've tried it on the latest Chrome and Firefox on Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [W3C DOM Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

#### focus

> The focus event occurs when an element receives focus either via a pointing device or by
>   tabbing navigation. This event is valid for the following elements: LABEL, INPUT, SELECT, 
>   TEXTAREA, and BUTTON.

#### blur

> The blur event occurs when an element loses focus either via the pointing device or by 
>   tabbing navigation. This event is valid for the following elements: LABEL, INPUT, SELECT, 
>   TEXTAREA, and BUTTON.

The jQuery docs state browsers extended the events to other elements, which I'm guessing means *blur* and *focus* are aliases for the more generic [*DOMFocusIn* and *DOMFocusOut* events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-uievents). Non-input elements aren't eligible to receive those by default though, and an element has to somehow gain focus before losing it - a *blur* still won't fire for every click outside the div.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550049/focus-on-a-non-input-anchor-element) mentions that giving an element a `tabindex` would allow that, and seems to work for me in Chrome after [modifying your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTMdY/1/). (Albeit with a fairly ugly outline.)

Comment: Yes I know that's what the W3C spec says, but as I said in my post, according to jQuery's documentation, in recent browsers the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types...I'm assuming FF6 and latest Chrome qualify.

Comment: @jbyrd - not sure why jQuery docs would supersede the W3C specs

Comment: @jbyrd I'm guessing that means "blur" and "focus" are aliased in browsers to the more generic DOM focus in/out events. Still, not every element is eligible for those by default - I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I knew, blur happens on *inputs* that had the focus, either way you say

> I expect the blur event to fire when I click anywhere that is not the div...right?

Not exactly, the blur event only happens for an element that had the focus first

So in order for a blur event to occur, you would first have to give focus to the div,  how is the div getting focus first?

If you are really try to determine if there was a click outside of your div, you need to attach a click handler to the document, and then check to see where your click came from.

```
var div_id = "#my_div";
var outsideDivClick = function (event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var box = jQuery(div_id);

  do {
    if (box[0] == target) {
      // Click occured inside the box, do nothing.
      return;
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  } while (target);   
}
jQuery(document).click(outsideDivClick);
```

Just remember that this handler will be run for EVERY click on the page. (in the past if i ha to use something like this, i attach the handler when I need it, and remove it when I no longer need to look for it)

Comment: Ok, so I updated the jsfiddle and added $('#test').focus();...but still no luck.

Comment: I think you missed my point, a `div` cannot have focus in the first place.

Comment: But I think you may have missed my original point that jQuery's documentation seems to suggest otherwise (I could be misinterpreting it but it seems pretty plain).

Comment: I understand how you read it. I just dont think it is the case, or at least I've never seen things work that way. In the past, I have always had to use the method I described above to check for clicks outside of a specific div

Comment: Right, ok - yeah that's interesting. I guess the docs could be wrong, then. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

A  can't "blur" because that would involve the div having focus in the first place. Non-input elements like a and textarea can have focus, which is what jQuery's documentation refers to.

What you need is the "mouseout" or "mouseleave" event (mouseleave doesn't bubble, mouseout does), which will be fired when the cursor leaves the div. If you need to have clicks, I would attach a "click" event to the body, as well as the div and stopping the event propagation on only the div:

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
    return false; // stop propagation
});
```

Or, if you're *really* determined, you can fake the appearance of a div with a  and some CSS rules :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen while you move your mouse over the box, you could use the [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event.

Comment: Ok I guess I can where you're coming from - but the question was really specifically about the blur event happening by clicking somewhere else.