# onblur handler not firing

Tags: jquery, onblur

I can't get this simple jQuery `onblur` handler to add the appropriate class. No errors are returned to the console and nothing happens on the blur event. What am I doing wrong?

I've verified that jQuery has been correctly loaded and is working properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nameInput').on('blur', function() {
    $('#nameInput').addClass('has-success');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="form" name="contactform.htm" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

      <div id="nameInput" class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label lead">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="John Doe">
          <span id="glyph" class="form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't anything syntactically wrong in the code  [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c0y6hmpf/)

Comment: @DLeh: Sorry about that. Here's the relevant code in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sean_t_taylor/70r3fc1e/25/

Comment: @GeorgeSpelvin `div` does not have `blur` event ;-) you need add handler to input element instead

Comment: also add relevant markup in your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery blur handler - not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536342/jquery-blur-handler-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

The blur event does not bubble, therefore it will never reach the div. If you instead used the focusout event, it would work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nameInput').on('focusout', function() {
    $('#nameInput').addClass('has-success');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="form" name="contactform.htm" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

      <div id="nameInput" class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label lead">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="John Doe">
          <span id="glyph" class="form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but seems this event not work in firefox: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout)

Comment: Works for me in firefox 34.0.5 and 38.0.1 Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You add handler to *div* instead of input, but *div* not raise *blur* event. So you need just add handler to your input, like

```
$('#nameInput input').on('blur', function() {
    $('#nameInput').addClass('has-success');
});
```

another solutions:

1. move id from *div* to *input*,
2. change in selector to input id

Answer (score -1):

you may want to test this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(document).on('blur', '#nameInput', function() { 
    $(this).addClass('has-success');
    });  
});
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful.