# How to focus on the text in top of page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form which has has to be accessible. If someone misses a mandatory field, the a error should show on the top of the page where I placed a div tag. Now, after I click the submit button, it should show an error message on the top of page and then have a focus so that the screen reader can read it without refreshing the page. I am just not being able to focus on that error. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.
Thanks
My code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "ERROR ON THE FORM";
}

function getfocus() {
    document.getElementById("errors").focus();
}

function printnfocus() {
    if (myFunction()) {
        getfocus();
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="errors"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Eligibility</legend> <input type="checkbox" id="citizen"> <label for="citizen">I am a U.S. citizen</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="18"> <label for="18">I am a 18 years old</label>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <br>
    </p>
    <form id="sex" name="sex">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sex:</legend> <label for="male">Male</label> <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br>
            <label for="female">Female</label> <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"><br>
            <br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <form>
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label> <span title="lblAstrisk" class="asterisk" style="color:red">*</span> <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required=""><br>
            <br>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="printnfocus()">Submit</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You **cannot focus on a non input** element. It this context you would need to animate the scrolling when the error is encountered.

Comment: Potentially related? [Focus on a non-input/anchor element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550049/focus-on-a-non-input-anchor-element)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo).  You can get the location of the `errors` div with this:

```
document.getElementById('errors').offsetTop
```

Comment: I partially understood it. I have a div reserved as a error container. Now, after someone clicks the submit button, I need to run myFunction() first to show error message and then the
window.scrollTo? I am not much experienced in Javascript. 
If you could please just point out where in my code should I edit and have the changes?

Thanks

Comment: I tried the steps posted my dc5. I could get the screen reader read the error message and get it focused using tabindex only if I tab all the way from start going through address bar, google search bar, frame and then the error message but when I click submit button, the focus is still in the same button. I want it to go to the top of the screen instead of sitting right there.

Comment: Ok guys, I got it working but I dont know if thats a good practise.
After I had the tabbed index, I called the function like this,
<input type="button" value="Submit2" onclick="myFunction(); getfocus();" />
and it worked!

Comment: I got one more question,
How can I have a error image focused first on the left and the message on the right?
I was trying a function,
document.getElementBy Id("errors").src="http://www.searchenginegenie.com/tools/images/Errorpage-Generator-Tool.png";
but its not working for some reason.
any idea?